# Determine animation time based on overflow width

Tags: jquery, css, algorithm, animation

This could be more of a general algorithm problem than a jquery problem.

My site is pulling data via an API to display information on the front page in divs. I'm using a js/jquery script to apply css animation to text which overflows past the width of its container. I have a css class which is applied if overflow exists, and that class has the animation properties set.

My issue is that some text overflows more than others, so I'm looking for a way to make the animation time variable depending on the amount of overflow. This way text only scrolls until the end of the line, then resets.

Here's the code in case there is a jquery solution to this I am missing.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('span.beer-info').each(function(i) {
        var element = $(this)
            .clone()
            .css({display: 'inline', width: 'auto', visibility: 'hidden'})
            .appendTo('body');

        if( element.width() > $(this).width() ) {
            $(this).addClass( "mover-1" );
        }

        element.remove();
    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/adam1496/uhLmgy5w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the animation duration based on width of elements this way:

```
    // ... 

    if( element.width() > $(this).width() ) {
        $(this).addClass( "mover-1" );

        // This is an example calculation, you can find a formula that works for you
        $(this).css('animation-duration', ($(this).width() / element.width() * 4) + 's')
    }
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks a lot.